# Not able to download Suitelet through suitescript 1.0

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, suitescript1.0

I have created a button to export the form data to simple Excel.
Everything is working file, even if i try to save this excel file in the file cabinet it gets saved correctly.
But when i try to downlaod the excel file, downloads wierd single cell file with special characters or system gives either an error or saves an empty excel file.
Can anyone help me in how to download the excel file from button click. I think i have issue in my responce.

My Code example is as follows:

```
  .
  .
  .
  xmlString += '</Table></Worksheet></Workbook>';// this is my xml string

  var xlsFile = nlapiCreateFile('test.xls', 'EXCEL', nlapiEncrypt(xmlString, 'base64'));
  response.writeFile(xmlFile);
}
```

error screenshot:

[image]

Comment: try to add some headers like `content-type`

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason for the response issue is because you are calling a non-existent variable "**xmlFile**" in writeFile();

try using this writeFile(**xlsFile**);

Comment: My Bad, I copied the incorrect var but in production the issue i m facing is the same.

Comment: based on the image, "Cannot find function writefile". In your function: do you have two parameters? like this generateXMLFile ( request, response ).

Comment: writeFile method is always usable if you are using the correct variable here.